# Пройтись циклом по свойствам класса

Tags: c#, winforms

Есть коллекция:

```
List<Person> persons = new List<Person>();
```

В коллекцию добавлены работники:

```
foreach (object item in CheckedListBox1.Items)
                {
                    persons.Add(new Person { Name = item.ToString() });
                }
```

Работники привязаны к компоненту CheckedListBox1:

```
var listBox = ((ListBox)CheckedListBox1);
            listBox.DataSource = persons;
            listBox.DisplayMember = "Name";
```

Есть массив:

```
TextBox[] TxtArray_d = new TextBox[] { this.TBox_d1, this.TBox_d2, this.TBox_d3, this.TBox_d4, this.TBox_d5, this.TBox_d6, this.TBox_d7, this.TBox_d8, this.TBox_d9, this.TBox_d10, this.TBox_d11, this.TBox_d12, this.TBox_d13, this.TBox_d14, this.TBox_d15, this.TBox_d16, this.TBox_d17, this.TBox_d18, this.TBox_d19, this.TBox_d20, this.TBox_d21, this.TBox_d22, this.TBox_d23, this.TBox_d24, this.TBox_d25, this.TBox_d26, this.TBox_d27, this.TBox_d28, this.TBox_d29, this.TBox_d30, this.TBox_d31 };
```

Текстбоксы массива привязываются к коллекции:

```
for (int num = 0; num < 31; ++num)
            {
                int num1;
                num1 = num + 1;

                TxtArray_d[num].DataBindings.Add("Text", persons, "Value" + num1);
            }
```

И Текстбоксы связаны со свойствами `Value1`, `Value2`, ...`Value31` класса:

```
public class Person
    {
            public string Name { get; set; }

            public string Value1 { get; set; }
            public string Value2 { get; set; }
            ...
            public string Value31 { get; set; }
    }
```

Как назначить всем свойствам (`Value1`, `Value2`, ...`Value31`) для всех элементов (Items) `CheckedListBox1` значение "В" с учетом цвета TextBox-ов (`TxtArray_d`)?

Comment: Переформулируйте вопрос, ничего не понятно

Comment: Код:   foreach (object item in CheckedListBox1.Items)
                {
                    foreach (TextBox prop in TxtArray_d)
                    {
                        if (prop.BackColor == Color.Pink) prop.Text = "В";
                    }
                }  - работает для одной строки в CheckedListBox1.

Comment: Что значит "значение В с учетом цвета текстбоксов"?

Comment: Уверены ли вы что вам нужно 31 публичное свойство? Может лучше использовать коллекцию?

Comment: а что это за код `foreach (object item in CheckedListBox1.Items)
{
 foreach (TextBox prop in TxtArray_d)
 {
  if (prop.BackColor == Color.Pink)
   prop.Text = "В";
 }
}`  ?  конкретно вот эта строка  `foreach (object item in CheckedListBox1.Items)`

Comment: "В" - это просто текст. 31 свойство - по числу дней (цветной день - выходной), подскажите пожалуйста что значит использовать коллекцию? Нужно после того как выполнена привязка, занести данные в свойства (в текстбоксы) для каждого работника.